# System.out.print keeps looping error

Tags: java

Hello there guys I've been trying to help my friend with this code that almost works. It's a simple Blackjack game which asks the user if they want another card write yes and if user writes no then his turn is ended and it should be the dealer's turn. The problem I'm having is that when I write no to end my turn it just keeps asking me the question if I want another card in the console. Thank you for you help.
Ex.

```
Another Card (yes/no)?: nO
Another Card (yes/no)?: no
Another Card (yes/no)?: no
Another Card (yes/no)?: no
Another Card (yes/no)?: nO
Another Card (yes/no)?: no
```

this is my code below:

```
while (playing == true ){
        System.out.print("Another Card (yes/no)?: ");
        anotherCard = keyboard.nextLine(); 


        if (anotherCard.equals("yes")) {

            nextCard = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
            cardTotal += nextCard;
            System.out.println("Card: " + nextCard);
            System.out.println("Total: " + cardTotal);

            if (cardTotal > 21) {               
            System.out.println("You busted, Dealer Wins"); 
            playing = false;       
            }  
            if (cardTotal == 21) {
            System.out.println("Player Wins"); 
            playing = false;
            }

            } 
           if (anotherCard.equals("no")) {
           dealerturn = true;

           if ((dealerturn == true) && (dTotal < 17)) {                           
                nextCard = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
                dTotal += nextCard;

                if (dTotal > 21) {                  
                System.out.println("Dealer Busts, You Win!");
                playing = false;

                }
            }
            else if ((dealerturn == true) && (dTotal > 17))  {
             if (dTotal > 21) {                  
                System.out.println("Dealer Busts, You Win!");
                playing = false;                       
                }
             }
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: What happens if the `dTotal` is 17?  It should just be an infinite loop of you typing `no`

Comment: You need an **else** statement at the end of your `if (anotherCard.equals("yes")) {....}` code block which will **break** out of the loop. `if (anotherCard.equals("yes")) {....} else { break; }` or  `if (anotherCard.equals("yes")) {....} else { playing = false; }`.

Comment: This is the perfect time to learn to use a debugger. Set a breakpoint and step through the code to see exactly what it is doing and what's causing the problem.

Comment: Also, you don't need `(dealerturn == true)` (which is the same as just `dealerturn`) right after setting `dealerturn = true;`

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't change `playing` to contain `false` when the user doesn't want to play:

```
if (anotherCard.equals("yes")) {
    ...
} else { // you should add this case:
    playing = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have no condition set to your "another card" prompt, and therefore it will prompt the user no matter what. To fix this, first verify dealerturn is false before printing the prompt along with the input.

so, change this:

```
System.out.print("Another Card (yes/no)?: ");
anotherCard = keyboard.nextLine();
```

into this:

```
if (dealerturn == false) {
    System.out.print("Another Card (yes/no)?: ");
    anotherCard = keyboard.nextLine(); 
}
```

PS. Next time you have a problem, post your code with the appropriate variable declarations and imports, so it's easier for people to help you faster.

Comment: `if (dealerturn == false)` is not neccessary since `dealerturn` already **is** a `boolean` value. The statement is thus equivalent to `if (!dealerturn)`, `!` means **not**.